# Could a synchronously-rotating planet in the goldilocks zone exist?

Tags: science-based, orbital-mechanics, weather

An earth like planet in terms of lots of water and an atmosphere.  The liquid water on the sunny side would evaporate due to the extreme heat and the snow and ice on the dark side would never melt due to lack of ever getting solar energy.  So would the build up of solid h2o on one side of the planet prevent the planet from maintaining a geosynchronous orbit?

If it could maintain a synchronous orbit, what would a planet's weather patterns look like?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "tidally locked," which has to do with the orbiting body (in this case, the planet.) Geosynchronous say to do with the central body, (in this case the sun)

Comment: More duplicates: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/127419/weather-and-climate-of-tidally-locked-inhabited-moon-with-oceans / https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69275/what-would-wind-currents-and-water-cycle-look-like-on-a-tidally-locked-planet

Comment: My apologies for the duplicates.  I did honestly try to search for some, but obviously used the wrong term.  Thanks for the resources and corrections.

Comment: If you recognize it is a duplicate, why did you accept an answer?

Comment: None of those "dupes" (suggested so far) ask if a tidally locked planet is possible, though asking that doe seem a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @L.Dutch Because the person gave a valid response.  Should that person not get credit (i.e. improved reputation) because I screwed up by asking a duplicate?

Comment: @Pelinore I was curious how the change in mass accumulating on one side of the planet due to the concentration of h2o would impact the planet being tidally locked.  The resources in both the answer provided and in the duplicates was helpful.

Comment: It's usually considered best to allow at least 24 hours to pass to get enough answers to be able to choose a best answer (in part to allow time for those in other time zones a chance to respond) it was locked too soon for that of course but locked questions are sometimes unlocked if appropriate (after editing etc).

Comment: Thanks @Pelinore, with the answer and the resources provided in the comments, I had the answers I was looking for.  But I will wait in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Water evaporating off the dayside and permanently condensing on the night side, resulting in a desiccated dayside, is *one* potential outcome, but only for a certain range of atmospheric density and composition and water content.

It actually takes surprisingly little atmosphere to distribute enough heat around a tidally-locked planet to ensure that liquid water can still exist on the night side. But even if you don't have that, a sufficient quantity of water will ensure that glaciers completely covering the night side will nevertheless creep back around into the light where their edges melt and re-introduce liquid water to the dayside.

As for what the weather will look like, the details are highly sensitive to things like exactly how much atmosphere there is, how fast the planet is rotating (equivalently, what its year length is), how much surface water there is, etc. In broad strokes: it is very easy to end up with either a single permanent cyclone over the sub-stellar point, or a pair of permanent counter-rotating cyclones on either side of the equator; it is also fairly typical to end up with high-altitude super-rotation of the atmosphere (similar to what we see on Venus), while surface-level prevailing winds tend to run from day to night along the equator, and from night to day over the poles.

Slightly more details can be found in, e.g., [Simulations of the Atmospheres of Synchronously Rotating Terrestrial
Planets](http://crack.seismo.unr.edu/ftp/ftp/pub/gillett/joshi.pdf), or any of a surprisingly large number of related papers.